# Import own .py files in anaconda spyder

Tags: python, anaconda

I've written my own mail.py module in spider (anaconda). I want to import this py file in other python (spider) files just by 'import mail'

I searched on the internet and couldn't find a clearly solution.

Answer (score 19):

To import any python script, it should exist in the PYTHONPATH. You can check this with the following code:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

To import your Python script:

1. Put both the scripts (main and the imported python script) in the
   same directory.
2. Add the location of the file to be imported to the
   sys.path.

For example, if the script is located as '/location/to/file/script.py':

```
 import sys
 sys.path.append('/location/to/file/')
 import script
```

Comment: Then I always needs to do : sys.path.append('location') ? Can I just place the .py file in a folder?

Comment: As I said, if mail.py is in the same folder as the other python file you want to import it into, nothing is required, simply `import mail` will work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, my files were in same folder, yet it was throwing an error while importing the "to_be_imported_file.py".

I had to run the "to_be_imported_file.py" seperately before importing it to another file.

I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Searched for an answer for this question to. To use a `.py` file as a **import module** from your main folder, you need to place both files in one folder or append a path to the location. If you storage both files in one folder, then check the **working directory** in the **upper right corner** of the spyder interface. Because of the wrong **working directory** you will see a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options, e.g.

- Place the mail.py file alongside the other python files (this works because the current working dir is on the PYTHONPATH.
- Save a copy of mail.py in the anaconda python environment's "/lib/site-packages" folder so it will be available for any python script using that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I did a slightly different solution approach that is less sophisticated.   When I start my anaconda terminal it is at a C prompt.    I just did a cd d:\mypython\lib  in the beginning window before starting python.     once I did that I could simply just import my own classes that I put in that library with "import MyClass as my"  then I was off and running.     It is interesting, I did 2 days of internet searching in my part time and could not find the answer either, until I asked a friend.

```
cd d:\mypython\lib
python
>>> import MyClass as my
>>> my1=my.MyClass()
>>> my1.doSomething()
```

worked for me on my anaconda / windows 10 environment python 3.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

when calling any function from another file, it should be noted to not import any library inside the function

Answer (score 0):

I believe the **easiest solution** is to place the directory containing your Python files into the Anaconda site-packages folder on your machine. I wrote an [article](https://medium.com/@mcmanus_data_works/how-to-import-your-python-scripts-with-anaconda-on-mac-and-windows-9b3fe5544d9d) outlining the whole process but, in short, you'll need to create a folder containing your python script and an `__init__.py` file. Then place that folder inside the site-packages folder in the Anaconda directory.

**On Windows** the `site-packages` directory is typically located at:
`C:\Users\[your_username]\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\`

**On Mac** the `site-packages` directory is typically located located at:
`Users/[your_username]/opt/anaconda3/lib/[python3.8]/site-packages/`

Notice, on Mac the Python version matters.  You'll need to look for the directory that corresponds to the `(base)` Python version used by Anaconda. Also, anything I've placed inside of square brackets in the file paths above need to be changed according to your particular machine and Python version.

The file structure should look something like this:

```
~/
 |__site-packages/
    |__your_folder/
        script.py
        __init__.py
```

After you have the folder containing your `script.py` and `__init__.py` file moved into the `site-packages` subdirectory of Anaconda, you'll be able to **import it from any script you run on your machine**.