# Python not finding own directory, "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ..." (Spyder IDE)

Tags: python, module, spyder

I'm currently trying to run an old github project and am running into an error with Python 3 in Spyder. I have

`from nmap_visualizer.db import Savednmap, User, db`

in my code and am getting a "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nmap_visualizer'"

However, the folder that contains db.py is called 'nmap_visualizer. This is my working directory and the file I'm trying to run this code in 'nmap.py' is in the same folder alongside db.py. In PYTHONPATH manager I've selected the nmap_visualizer folder for my path. In 'Preferences' under 'Run' I have 'Default working directory is:' 'The directory of the file being executed'.

When I try `from .db import Savednmap, User, db` I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.db'; '**main**' is not a package"

I do have an **init**.py file which runs and imports db perfectly fine with `from . import db`, but I'm not sure why my 'nmap.py' file is failing.

Comment: is `__init__.py` inside the `nmap_visualizer` directory?

Comment: If the file you're trying to run is in the same folder then the import need to be `from db import Savednmap, User, db`. No need for any `.` in front of `db`.

Answer (score -1):

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409424/import-own-py-files-in-anaconda-spyder) helped for me: adding the directory to pythonpath

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

sys.path.append("\\folder with script")
```